# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime FormatException

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I get an exception with the error message -

> "System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid
> DateTime."

on the following line:

```
DateTime RecDate = RecDateSearch == string.Empty ? Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1970").Date : Convert.ToDateTime(RecDateSearch).Date;
```

[image]

When choose day in the date less than 12 like 10/1/2021 or 12/12/2020, I get no exception. But when choose day in the date more than 12 like 20/1/2020 or 23/12/2020, I get this exception.

This is my javascript code -

```js
    var myTable = $('#m_table_1').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "scrollY": 200,
        "scrollX": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '@Url.Action("AllPOSDonations", "POSDonation")',
            "type": "POST"
        },
        columns: [
        { data: "Id" },
        { data: "No" },
        {
            data: "DonationDate", render: function (d) {
                return moment(d).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        }
```

This is my razor code -

```html
 <div class="form-group" id="datepickerDiv">
<input type="text" id="recDate" class="form-control" data-date-container='#datepickerDiv' />
</div>
```

Comment: What language/region have you got set, does it use "mm/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1970").Date` Don't do that. Call the `DateTime` constructor and pass in numbers. There is no good reason to use `Convert` with a fixed date.

Answer (score 1):

Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(RecDateSearch, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: when use this line , i got this erorr DataTables warning: table id=m_table_1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

As you supply a well-formatted string for a date value, use the more forgiving `Parse` method, and you can reduce to:

```cs
DateTime RecDate = RecDateSearch == string.Empty ? new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) : DateTime.Parse(RecDateSearch);

Console.WriteLine(RecDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Results:

```cs
string RecDateSearch = string.Empty;
// RecDate -> 1970-01-01

string RecDateSearch = "2020/01/20";
// RecDate -> 2020-01-20
```

Comment: when search by date , this massage appear (No data available in table
)

Comment: Double-check your date value and the record value.